# How can I use AMD drivers for AMD A10-8700P Radeon R6 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: drivers

I open *Software & Updates*> *Additional Drivers*. It's currently : opensource, tested.

I select any of the others (Proprietary) and apply.

But it won't let me swap, just goes back to the open source one.

Answer (score 0):

Load Ubuntu onto a flashdrive/CD and load the Ubuntu live option at boot. If everything load fine and Ubuntu runs ok you should be set, if any other issues come up you should be able to fix them.